# Using configuration properties to determine loop count in camel

Tags: configuration, apache-camel

Here is my code.
I am figuring out how to use configuration properties to determine loop count.
the configuration properties seems to read it as string class type.

```
PropertiesComponent pc = new PropertiesComponent();
pc.setLocation("classpath:app.properties");
getContext().addComponent("properties", pc);

from("direct:a")
    .routeId("CheckDevices")
    .loop("{{Device.count}}")  //loop expect a integer. how do i convert ?
    .to("mock:result");
```

The configuration file:

## app.properties

Device.Count=5

Answer (score 0):

```
.loop(Integer.valueOf("{{Device.count}}") // this does the job
```